# Interact with vue-multiselect programmatically

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-multiselect

Tried to open the select with these:

```js
document.querySelector('.multiselect').click()
document.querySelector('.multiselect__tags').click()
document.querySelector('#languages').click()
document.querySelector('.multiselect__spinner').click()
document.querySelector('.multiselect__content-wrapper').click()
```

**This one works** by selecting the item directly but in my case the element needs to be visible so I have to open the drawer anyways.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.multiselect__option')[1].click()
```

In order to do so I tried iterating trough entire vue-multiselect node tree and sending a click to every single element :

```js
items = items.querySelector('#languages-input')
items = items.querySelectorAll('*')

const timer = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms))

for(i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    console.log(items[i])
    items[i].click()
    await timer(1000)
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to trigger a `click` so you can select these items? Is that what it is?

Comment: Yes exactly. This is the element that I am trying to interact with: https://vue-multiselect.js.org/

Comment: Can I ask why? Your `vue-multiselect` component has a binding for its values that you can  set which will replicate the same behavior without trying to manipulate the DOM. e.g. `this.value = 'cool'` will select and highlight the option `cool`

Comment: Writing WebdriverIO tests. Tried that as well. It seems that this component is using `<input>` only for structure because it does not hold the real value. Even if something is selected the `value=""`

Comment: You don't want to use VueJS' state rather than selecting DOM elements? What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: These tests will run on app instances that are hosted and are very much like production version. So dealing with VueJS state from tests is not a good option in this case

Comment: Don't forget to @ me next time if you want me to be notified of your comment. I guess that you could run it in a 99% similar environment, just change `production` to `test` and allow it to be available for testing. Not sure if it is actually how this may be done. Otherwise, having to deal with an imperative way is pretty cumbersome. Good luck tho!

Comment: For me, just clicking on the `div.multiselect` works, as long as it retains focus. You can only do this with a web driver, but not from the console of the same browser. I'm currently using vue-multiselect version 2.1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The drawer is hidden using `display: none`.

In order to open the drawer:

```
drawer = document.querySelector('.multiselect__content-wrapper')
drawer.style.display = 'block'
```

To select/deselect items by index:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.multiselect__option')[0].click()
```